# Entity Framework stored procedure: Function Import to Complex Type, Error on Get Column Information

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I am working on a project in `VS2012` while using `MySQL` database and `Entity Framework 5.0.0`.

When I try to create a new `Complex` type from a stored procedure, I get an error when clicking "Get Column Information" button:

> The selected stored procedure or function returns no columns.

My stored procedure code is as following:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SearchAlgemeenSet;

Delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE SearchAlgemeenSet(IN in_searchQuery VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
      SELECT Blokken, Jaargang, Werk_Uren
FROM algemeensets
WHERE Blokken LIKE in_searchQuery 
   OR Jaargang LIKE in_searchQuery 
   OR Werk_Uren LIKE in_searchQuery;
END
//

Delimiter ;
```

I'm positive that it returns columns if the `in_searchQuery` parameter has a match.

In my research, I have found plenty solutions for Microsoft SQL database. But none of those solutions apply to MySQL database.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm positive that it returns columns, if the `in_searchQuery`
>   parameter has a match.

Because you are not using any wild card for partial search, unless it finds an *exact* match, for `in_searchQuery` value, no rows will be returned. For partial match to happen, you need to use wild card symbol `'%'` with the `in_searchQuery` value.

Modified procedure, should be like the following:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SearchAlgemeenSet;

Delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE SearchAlgemeenSet(IN in_searchQuery VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

    set @search_criteria := concat( '%', in_searchQuery, '%' );

    SELECT Blokken, Jaargang, Werk_Uren
    FROM algemeensets
    WHERE Blokken LIKE @search_criteria 
       OR Jaargang LIKE @search_criteria
       OR Werk_Uren LIKE @search_criteria;
END;
//

Delimiter ;
```

When no search criteria has any matches found, and empty set would be returned.
In your scripting language, you have to check, in advance, whether the procedure has returned any results or not. Based on that, you can show a message that no data found or you can perform other actions.